# Another vertical-alignment issue

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align an icon on the bottom right of a div:

```
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:50%">
    <div class="col-xs-11">Foo<br/><span style="font-style:italic">Bar</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="vertical-align: bottom; display:inline-block">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/640/

I've read posts that suggest using display: table-cell or inline-block, along with vertically-align:bottom. This does not seem to work in this particular case. Why is that?

Comment: Your Fiddle code is different than the code that you've posted in your question.

Comment: Anyway, add `text-align: right` if you want that **Hello** to be aligned on the bottom right. ------------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/EAUcW/639/)

Comment: Sorry, updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/641/)

**CSS**

```
.bottom-right-icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:50%; position: relative;">
    <div class="col-xs-11">Foo<br/><span style="font-style:italic">Bar</span></div>
    <div class="bottom-right-icon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the addition of `position: relative` on `div.row`, and the removal of the bootstrap `col-xs-1` class from the icon.

Then, the rest is just pushing the icon to where it belongs via `absolute` positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there was the answer somewhere on SO, but can't find original post.

The below should solve your problem:

```
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #000; width:50%">
    <div class="col-xs-11" style="vertical-align: bottom; display:inline-block;float:none;">Foo
        <br/><span style="font-style:italic">Bar</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="vertical-align: middle; display:inline-block;float:none;"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/643/)